# I cannot access to nitrogen/inets server from any machine but the localhost

Tags: erlang, ubuntu-12.04, nitrogen, inets

Thanks to many discussions in this forum, I found that I should be able to build the application I was planning to do for home usage based on Nitrogen.

So I ran into Nitrogen tutorials, Demo and docs, and start to do some tests based on the self contained inets/nitrogen site. Everything was going well until I wanted to try to access my new website from another PC. Of course I had to tune my box first in order to route wan requests to lan... But after a day searching, reading and testing, I am still stuck...

What I have tested:

- call the website from local host using intranet IP address or
  localhost: OK
- from local host, access to static pages and different
  "my_page.erl" path : OK
- access from another PC using lan address : I
  can catch the ethernet frames using wireshark, but the connexion
  fails with timeout.
- access from another PC using wan address : I can
  catch the ethernet frames using wireshark (after address
  translation), but the connexion fails with timeout.

[image: screen capture of wireshark and netstat results]

- access from local PC using wan address : I can
  catch the ethernet frames out and in using wireshark but the connexion fails with timeout.
- I have put some ?DEBUG macros in my code: but none of them is reached.
- I tried an access to a static file: same behavior.
- I checked using netstat -ap that the process beam.smp is listening the right port: OK
- I checked for a response frame on external PC using smartsniff: no response for both lan and wan accesses.
- I tested different ports and port routing.

I must miss something obvious, is there something to configure in order to make this work? or a test I can do? because I have no more ideas.

context:

- browser firefox 16.0.2 and chromium 21.0.1138 running on windows XP 32
- server running on Ubuntu 12.04
- default nitrogen/inets application (modified port to 8020)
- Erlang 15B02
- nprocreg, 0.2.0
- parsetools, 2.0.7
- common_test, 1.6.2
- mnesia, 4.7.1
- ssl, 5.1
- public_key, 0.16
- compiler, 4.8.2
- xmerl, 1.3.2
- runtime_tools, 1.8.9
- crypto, 2.2
- inets, 5.9.1
- sasl, 2.2.1
- stdlib, 1.18.2
- kernel, 2.15.2

Comment: Just so it's clear, are you running this on a Virtual Machine?

Comment: No, Linux Ubuntu is the main OS of the system running the server. The browser is on separate laptop. I use the console mode of Nitrogen.

Comment: It's kinda obvious, but you didn't mention firewall settings. Have you checked them on both boxes? And also try to run something other than nitrogen on the same port (like netcat -l -p <PORT>) just to make sure it's network level issue and not the application's

Comment: Also, you could try running something like nmap on another machine (`nmap <target ip>`) just to see if the machine is accessible.

Comment: To Syphoon, well I was expecting something obvious, and I cannot complain! Thank you for the hint, I spent so much time in setting my box that I totally forget the firewall and there was very few chance that I remember it in the next hours. Of course, now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enter this answer just to mention that the problem was in my firewall configuration as Syhpoon pointed it, and so it is solved.

To other members, what should I do with this question? I don't think it is a great help for other people apart that it is a reminder for all of us who are stuck to:

- List all the elements playing in the game
- "Ask a little help from my friends" ... not too late :o)

Should I delete the topic?

Comment: I think you're fine leaving it up. At the very least, if someone else runs into the same problem, at least it'll remind them to check their firewall settings before moving forward.