# Erlang gen_udp sending packets to ip address?

Tags: erlang, udp, ip-address

I tried using the following code for a simple test to send packets across the Internet. I did check to see if the localhost version works with the following commands and it did work but it doesn't work if I replace localhost (127.0.0.1) with a real internet address, mine. I just get 0 on the client side and nothing changes with the server side, although using localhost is the same with the server side.

Server side:

`udp_test:start_server().`

Client side:

`udp_test:client(40).`

Simple enough but when I replace 127.0.0.1 with my ip address I get nothing ( I turned off the firewall too). The basic topology of my home network consists of a wireless modem (using dsl) and my computer is connected via a wireless usb card. There are about two other active computers on the network. I thought that may have something to do with the connection.

I also wondered how could I modify the code so I can type `udp_test:client(40,127.0.0.1).`
instead and change the client function to accept two arguments in udp_test? I tried simply doing `client(N,ip)` and changing the function `gen_udp:send(Socket, "ip",,)` but that came up with a no matching clause error.

```
-module(udp_test).
-export([start_server/0, client/1]).

start_server() ->
    spawn(fun() -> server(4000) end).

%% The server         
server(Port) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(Port, [binary]),
    io:format("server opened socket:~p~n",[Socket]),
    loop(Socket).

loop(Socket) ->
    receive
    {udp, Socket, Host, Port, Bin} = Msg ->
        io:format("server received:~p~n",[Msg]),
        N = binary_to_term(Bin),
        Fac = fac(N),
        gen_udp:send(Socket, Host, Port, term_to_binary(Fac)),
        loop(Socket)
    end.

fac(0) -> 1;
fac(N) -> N * fac(N-1).

%% The client

client(N) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(0, [binary]),
    io:format("client opened socket=~p~n",[Socket]),
    ok = gen_udp:send(Socket, "127.0.0.1", 4000, 
              term_to_binary(N)),
    Value = receive
        {udp, Socket, _, _, Bin} = Msg ->
            io:format("client received:~p~n",[Msg]),
            binary_to_term(Bin)
        after 2000 ->
            0
        end,
    gen_udp:close(Socket),
    Value.
```

Answer (score 1):

write {127,0,0,1} instead of "127.0.0.1".

[Ip address](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#type-ip_address)

Comment: I tried `gen_udp:send(Socket, {127.0.0.1},,)` in the above code and got two errors compiling. `udp_test.erl:39: syntax error before: '.'
udp_test.erl:10: function client/1 undefined
error`. Using "127.0.0.1" works btw but my ip address doesnt work?

Comment: Please, try it with a comma and not with a dot.  {127,0,0,1}

Comment: That did work in my code using `gen_udp:send(Socket, {127,0,0,1},,)` and I tested it. I then tried my ip address and that still gets 0 for the client side.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work now:

udp_test:client(4).
client opened socket=#Port<0.2267>
server received:{udp,#Port<0.2263>,{127,0,0,1},64462,<<131,97,4>>}
client received:{udp,#Port<0.2267>,{127,0,0,1},4000,<<131,97,24>>}
24

Comment: Did you try using `udp_test:client(4).` sending a packet to your ip address, not 127.0.0.1 but through the Internet?

Comment: Did you check your firewall setting. I got lost with te same issue - see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588803/i-cannot-access-to-nitrogen-inets-server-from-any-machine-but-the-localhost ...

Comment: @Pascal Yup I turned off my firewall. I think I need to fix the port forwarding on my dsl modem.